# What is gets() equivalent in C11?

Tags: c, c11

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/)

> The most recent revision of the C standard (2011) has definitively 
>   removed this function from its specification
>
> The function is deprecated in C++ (as of 2011 standard, which follows
>   C99+TC3).

I just wanted to know what is the alternative to `gets()` in C11 standard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C11 `gets` has been substituted by `gets_s` that has the following declaration:

```
char *gets_s(char *str, rsize_t n);
```

This function will read at most `n-1` chars from `stdin` into `*str`. This is to avoid the buffer overflow vulnerability inherent to `gets`. The function `fgets` is also an option. From http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets:

> The **gets()** function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks. It cannot be used safely (unless the program runs in an environment which restricts what can appear on stdin). For this reason, the function has been deprecated in the third corrigendum to the C99 standard and removed altogether in the C11 standard. **fgets()** and **gets_s()** are the recommended replacements.
>
> Never use **gets()**.

Given that `gets_s` is defined in an extension to the standard, only optionally implemented, you should probably write your programs using `fgets` instead. If you use `fgets` on `stdin` your program will also compile in earlier versions of C. But keep in mind the difference in the behavior: when `gets_s` has read `n-1` characters **it keeps reading until a new line or end-of-file is reached**, discarding the input. So, with `gets_s` you are always reading an entire line, even if only a part of it can be returned in the input buffer.

Comment: It should be noted that `gets_s` is optional, need not be present if the implementation doesn't define `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`, and if it does, need `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` defined to 1 (if that's not defined at all, it's implementation-defined whether the functions in annex K are included in the respective headers).

Comment: `fgets` should be used. `gets_s` is an optional interface that only exists on Windows and was mentioned in the standard only for political reasons. Pretty much everybody outside of MS finds the _s interfaces misguided and harmful. Reportedly the standardized behavior of some or all of the _s interfaces even differs from the only existing implementations (the MS ones), making their use even more harmful.

Comment: I suspect that you have misunderstood the behavior of gets_s. Just like fgets, it reads at most n-1 characters. The difference is that gets_s stops if it encounters a new line character. Nothing in the standard indicates that it keeps reading after n-1. Don't confuse the standard version with various non-standard implementations that existed before C11.

Comment: @Lundin Do you have access to the text of the C11 standard? All references I can find document this behaviour, including this "committee draft" http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf: *Unlike the fgets function, gets_s maintains a
one-to-one relationship between input lines and successful calls to gets_s. Programs that use gets
expect such a relationship.*

Comment: @Joni Yes I have the actual C11 standard and not just a draft. I will include the text in the "informative" answer I made, for reference.

Comment: @Lundin The text I quoted is from a footnote on the page that specifies the behavior of `gets_s`. Was it removed from the final version? Just curious..

Comment: @Joni Ah ok, well nothing appears to have changed between the draft and the standard, the text regarding gets_s is identical. I posted the relevant, normative part of the standard (btw please note that foot notes are never normative in ISO standards). The only differences between fgets and gets_s, is that fgets can be used on any kind of file stream and not just stdin, while gets_s automatically stops reading if it encounters \n.

Comment: @Lundin: Would another major difference be that gets_s() omits the newline from the buffer, thus avoiding the need to scan the newly-received string in order to find and eliminate it?

Answer (score 9):

Others have already answered the question. For the sake of completeness, this is the C standard's recommendation:

ISO9899:2011 K.3.5.4.1/6

> Recommended practice
>
> The fgets function allows properly-written programs to safely process input lines too long to store in the result
>   array. In general this requires that callers of fgets pay attention to
>   the presence or absence of a new-line character in the result array.
>   Consider using fgets (along with any needed processing based on
>   new-line characters) instead of gets_s.

So you should use **fgets** whenever possible.

**EDIT**

gets_s behavior is specified to be:

ISO9899:2011 K.3.5.4.1/4

> Description
>
> The gets_s function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n
>   from the stream pointed to by stdin, into the array pointed to by s. No additional
>   characters are read after a new-line character (which is discarded) or after end-of-file.
>   The discarded new-line character does not count towards number of characters read. A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.
>
> If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, or if a read
>   error occurs during the operation, then s[0] is set to the null character, and the other
>   elements of s take unspecified values.

Comment: Note that `gets_s()` reports a constraint violation if there is neither a newline nor EOF within the `n-1` characters; it is an error to get an overlong line.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `fgets` or `gets_s`:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Console/Usefgetstoreadstringfromstandardinput.htm

Answer (score 4):

According to `man 3 gets`, `fgets`.

Comment: The gets equivalent in the C11 standard is gets_s, although it should technically be the same thing as fgets(..., stdin);

Comment: "In an optional annex added for political reasons" is hardly "in the C11 standard". You will not find a C11-conformant version of the _s functions anywhere, because nobody plans to implement them.

Comment: @R.. Annex K of C11 is normative, even though it is not mandatory to implement. What this means in practice, is that C implementations can no longer contain weird, non-standard gets_s functions that have a behavior that collides with the standard. I also bet that GCC will implement these functions: that compiler just loves optional, redundant, pointless features. I would however recommend fgets(), for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Since they're library functions, they're outside the scope of GCC. If you mean glibc, I'm pretty sure the maintainers have already expressed a strong disinterest in adding them. Also, I'm not even sure that non-standard versions of the functions are non-conformant unless an implementation advertises (via the appropriate predefined macros) that it supports Annex K. If MS's functions really do differ from the standard, I think the chance of them getting changed is approximately zero; they don't seem to care about conformance anyway.