# gets_s giving error with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, fgets, c11, gets

`gets_s()` function is not working on my compiler. I am using codeblocks with GCC.

This is the error :

```
undefined reference to '_imp_gets_s.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this error.

Comment: `gets_s` it self is an error, use `fgets()`.

Comment: Don't use `gets` use `fgets()`

Comment: But c11 states that gets function no longer used.gets_s is used instead

Comment: gets_s() is an extension. Not part of std C, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12893774/2235885

Comment: @joop, to be exact, Annex K is an *option*, and this is the problem here, glibc doesn't implement it.

Answer (score 7):

You should be using `fgets()` over `gets()` or `gets_s()`.

Referrring `C11`, §K.3.5.4.1, paragraph 6,

> The `fgets()` function allows properly-written programs to safely process input lines too long to store in the result array. In general this requires that callers of `fgets()` pay attention to the presence or absence of a new-line character in the result array. Consider using `fgets()` (along with any needed processing based on new-line characters) instead of `gets_s()`.