# Systemc Error with the library

Tags: c++, hardware, fpga, systemc, asic

I installed the SystemC library 2.3.1 using [this](https://rkrara.blogspot.com.by/2012/12/install-systemc-230-on-linux.html?showComment=1468411507294) tutorial.

I wrote this hello world example:

```
//hello.cpp
#include <systemc.h>

SC_MODULE (hello_world) {
  SC_CTOR (hello_world) {
  }

  void say_hello() {
    cout << ”Hello World systemc-2.3.0.\n”;
  }
};

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  hello_world hello(“HELLO”);
  hello.say_hello();
  return(0);
}
```

and compiled with this command:

```
export SYSTEMC_HOME=/usr/local/systemc230/
g++ -I. -I$SYSTEMC_HOME/include -L. -L$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-linux -Wl,-rpath=$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-linux -o hello hello.cpp -lsystemc -lm
```

When I compile the code, I got a error with the library:

```
In file included from hello.cpp:1:0:
/usr/local/systemc230/include/systemc.h:118:16: error: ‘std::gets’ has not been declared
     using std::gets;
                ^~~~
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you enable C++11 as default flag for g++ ? (with an alias for example)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much for this question! You probably save me several days...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::gets` has been removed in C++11 (See [What is gets() equivalent in C11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893774/what-is-gets-equivalent-in-c11))

If you're building using C++11 flag (maybe with a g++ alias), you have to disable this line in `systemc.h`.

Replace

```
using std::gets;
```

with

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus < 201103L)
using std::gets;
#endif
```

Comment: With this fix the error is now this:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsystemc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If you're working on a x64 Linux, you have to change
g++ -I. -I$SYSTEMC_HOME/include -L. -L$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-linux -Wl,-rpath=$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-linux -o hello hello.cpp -lsystemc -lm
to 
g++ -I. -I$SYSTEMC_HOME/include -L. -L$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-linux64 -Wl,-rpath=$SYSTEMC_HOME/lib-linux64 -o hello hello.cpp -lsystemc -lm

Answer (score 2):

As guyguy333 mentioned, in new versions, g++ is an alias for C++11.
so adding `-std=c++98` would solve the problem.
The compile command may like

```
$ g++ -std=c++98 -lsystemc -pthread main.cpp -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have copy pased the code from webpage as it is. Please remember “” and "" are not the same thing. On line 8

```
cout << ”Hello World systemc-2.3.0.\n”;
```

replace it with

```
cout << "Hello World systemc-2.3.0.\n";
```

and on line 13

```
hello_world hello(“HELLO”);
```

replace it with

```
hello_world hello("HELLO");
```

And then execute the code again.
GoodLuck.

Comment: I fixed this and the same error with the library still.